# Flash AS3 TileList DataProvider getIndex

Tags: actionscript-3, cellrenderer, tilelist

I am using the Flash code provided on the web. Im modifying it as to differentiate the colour of odd numbered row Background and the even one. But I cant get access to the data.index. How do I get access to the index?

```
import fl.controls.TileList;
import fl.core.UIComponent;
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import fl.events.ListEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

public class CellRendererExample extends Sprite
{
    public function CellRendererExample() {
        var index:int;
        var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
        var totalEntries:uint = 42;
        var i:uint;
        for(i=0; i<totalEntries; i++) {
            dp.addItem( { label:"Item "+i ,index:i} );            
        }

        var myTileList = new TileList();
        myTileList.dataProvider = dp;
        myTileList.allowMultipleSelection = true;
        myTileList.columnWidth = 125;
        myTileList.rowHeight = 30;
        myTileList.columnCount = 1;
        myTileList.rowCount = 6;
        myTileList.move(10,10);
        myTileList.direction = "VERTICAL";


        for(i=0; i<totalEntries; i++) {
        if (dp.label[i].index%2==0){
        myTileList.setStyle('cellRenderer', MyRenderer);    }
        else{
            myTileList.setStyle('cellRenderer', MyAnotherRenderer); 
            }
        }


        addChild(myTileList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is completely wrong:

```
if (dp.label[i].index%2==0){
```

DataProvider just contains your items, similar to Array. `label[i]` won't return anything, and `index` is not a property of that object (`label` and `index` are properties of the object that you put into the DataProvider).

First, your `i` variable is actually the index. You can check if `i % 2 == 0`.
If you want any specific information from the DataProvider (you put different indexes in the elements), you could use `dp.getItemAt(i)` -> this will give you each item, and you can check it's properties: `dp.getItemAt(i).index % 2 == 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have got the trace of index but my main purpose is to change the odd numbered row background color. right now the whole TileList is using the "MyAnotherRenderer" style. I hope I can use the odd ones with that Class. and the even numbered row with the MyRendered class.

Comment: I think its using the last setStyle thats written

Comment: It's using `MyAnotherRenderer`, because of the fact that the check for the odd row was wrong. Try the new check, and trace out if the code inside it is executed.

Comment: Im sorry I have used the new check, but the result is still the same. If I delete the `MyRenderer` , it use the style of `MyAnotherRenderer`  and vice versa. I have put the new If-Statement above.

Comment: As I said - trace everything out - the check, and if the check is passing.

Comment: The check passed , the number came out. but still the style differentiation isnot happening..

Comment: Don't know about that, should see the code. This is another problem anyways.